# NSDictionary objectForKey throws Exception

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've built an XML parser in Objective-C and the message objectForKey throws an NSException but I don't know why.

```
aPicture = [[Picture alloc] init];

aPicture.pictureID = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
```

Here is the message of the exception that i don't understand:

```
2010-08-09 21:27:32.223 rh[6375:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Picture setPictureID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x592e0b0'
```

Answer (score -1):

After a long search i got my mistake...
I have forgotton to synthezise the pictureID selector.

....

Comment: "A long search" being "2 minutes after I posted my question"? ;)

Comment: yeah but i search a half hour before i posted it ^^